# Jesenger laravel Mongodb many to many relationship?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

In Jessenger laravel mongodb package i have two models

belongs to many relationship

> Property

and

> Application

i want to fetch all the aaplication with properties in it,.
right now i am doing this ,.

$application = Application::with('properties')->find($application->_id);

it returns the only single property against single application,.

what i want is to fetch all properties against all applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is to find a record using the primary key. You will need to use `get` to find all records with matching data. Try this:

```
$applications = Application::with('properties')->get();
dd($applications);
```

Check out the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: There is limitation that as i am using Model of the liberary https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/8d06ac5342b00705e2dd7a78ea84368a3c7ed697/tests/RelationsTest.php#L325 i can only use the method defined in it ,.,

Comment: What's the limitation?

Comment: We can not use all the functions on laravel model , i can only implement the functions overridden by Jessenger model.

Comment: Hmm. Laravel mongo is the mongo implementation of eloquent. By right it should support `get` too. I don't get it why you say no? https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#query-builder

Comment: I figure out the problem was in the jessenger versions and laravel versions ,. in the latest jessenger version they have reolved the issue ,., i have to change the files and it started working,., thanks for your time and accept your answer,.